# Why does writing to I2C is too slow in Python comparing to C?

Tags: python, i2c, gcc

I am trying to find out why the same code in Python works 25 times slower than C even if I use CDLL, when I try to write into I2C. Below I will describe all the details what I am doing step by step.

The version of Raspberry PI: Raspberry PI 3 Model B

OS: Raspbian Buster Lite Version:July 2019

GCC version: gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0

Python version: Python 3.7.3

The device I am working with though I2C is MCP23017. All I do is writing 0 and 1 to the pin B0. Here is my code written in C:

```
// test1.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <time.h>


int init() {
    int fd = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR);
    ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, 0x20);
    return fd;
}


void deinit(int fd) {
    close(fd);
}


void makewrite(int fd, int v) {
    char buffer[2] = { 0x13, 0x00 };
    buffer[1] = v;
    write(fd, buffer, 2);
}


void mytest() {
    clock_t tb, te;
    int n = 1000;

    int fd = init();

    tb = clock();
    int v = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        makewrite(fd, v);
        v = 1 - v;
    }
    te = clock();

    printf("Time: %.3lf ms\n", (double)(te - tb) / n / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1e3);

    deinit(fd);
}


int main() {
    mytest();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run it with the command:

```
gcc test1.c -o test1 && ./test1
```

It gives me the result:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/dev/i2c_example $ gcc test1.c -o test1 && ./test1
Time: 0.020 ms
```

I may conclude that writing to the pin takes 0.02 milliseconds.

After that I create SO-file to be able to access the written functions from my Python script:

```
gcc -c -fPIC test1.c -o test1.o && gcc test1.o -shared -o test1.so
```

And my Python script to test:

```
# test1.py

import ctypes
from time import time

test1so = ctypes.CDLL("/home/pi/dev/i2c_example/test1.so")

test1so.mytest()

n = 1000

fd = test1so.init()

tb = time()
v = 1
for _ in range(n):
    test1so.makewrite(fd, v)
    v = 1 - v
te = time()
print("Time: {:.3f} ms".format((te - tb) / n * 1e3))

test1so.deinit(fd)
```

This provides me the result:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/dev/i2c_example $ python test1.py
Time: 0.021 ms
Time: 0.516 ms
```

I cannot understand why the call of `makewrite` is 25 times slower in Python though actually I call the same C-code. I also researched that if I comment `write(fd, buffer, 2);` in `test1.c` or change `fd` to `1`, the times given by the Python script are compatible, there is no such huge difference.

```
// in test1.c
write(fd, buffer, 2); -> write(1, buffer, 2);
```

Running C-program:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/dev/i2c_example $ gcc test1.c -o test1 && ./test1
...Time: 0.012 ms
```

Running Python-program:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/dev/i2c_example $ python3 test1.py 
...Time: 0.009 ms
...Time: 0.021 ms
```

It confused me a lot. Can anybody tell me why does it happen and how can I improve my performance in Python regarding the access via I2C using C-DLL?

**Summary:**

**Descriptor: 1 (stdout)**

Execution time of makewrite in C purely: **0.009 ms**

Execution time of makewrite in C called as C-DLL function from Python: **0.021 ms**

*The result is expectable. This difference is not so high. It can be explained that Python loop and its statements are not as efficient as in C, thus it increases the execution time.*

**Descriptor: I2C**

Execution time of makewrite in C purely: **0.021 ms**

Execution time of makewrite in C called as DLL function from Python: **0.516 ms**

*After switching the file descriptor to I2C the execution time in pure C increased in around `0.012 ms`, so I would expect the execution time for calling from Python: `0.021 ms + 0.012 ms = 0.033 ms`, because all changes I've done are inside of `makewrite`, so Python is supposed not to know this internal thing (because it's packed in so-file). But I have `0.516 ms` instead of `0.033 ms` that confuses me.*

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you expect.  Isn't this simply the difference between a compiled program (C) and an interpreted script (Python).

Comment: No, in both cases the compiled C-code is executed (as executable file `test1` and as a function in `test1.so`), but it works differently somehow. Look at the Python code carefully, please.

Comment: I did look at the Python code.  I suggest you do the same and look at all the Python statements between your time stamps.

Comment: @joan "I also researched that if I comment write(fd, buffer, 2); in test1.c or change fd to 1, the times given by the Python script is compatible, there is no such huge difference." plus `test1so.makewrite` is a call from SO that executes C compiled commands, it's not a simple Python-statement.

Comment: I can only comment on the question.  If you think there is additional relevant information then edit it into your question.

Comment: I think joan's point was about the range loop, which is python, vs. the C for loop in mytest().  WRT to commenting out the `write`, C compilers are monsters of optimization, and, since that function is then clearly a no-op, it is optimized right out (ie, it is never actually called).  You might find this difference if you use `-O0` with `gcc`.

Comment: @goldilocks Adding `-O0`  doesn't change the times I get.

Comment: ctypes has a lot of work to do to check types of the parameters given to "makewrite", convert them to C values, prepare the stack and convert back a possible result of the call (although it isn't used here).

Comment: I think the best thing for you to do is to edit this down a bit, minimising or removing reference to the Raspberry Pi since the brand of hardware isn't relevant (but do mention it is an ARM system), and post it on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), where there are almost 1000 questions tagged 'python' and 'dll'.  Include "C-DLL" in the title, since its knowledge of that that is probably most significant to finding an answer.